# Setting UI contents only adds last line

Tags: java, user-interface

Basically what I'm doing here is importing the contents of a text file into user input fields (there are 7 of them. I run a loop to go through them for command [i]. The code works fine within the console, but it wont work for the GUI as it only inputs the last line for each field. Have you got any clue what the problem is? Here is the UI:

http://imageshack.us/f/692/21778853.jpg

As you can see, it prints into the console fine, but when I import data by clicking import on the GUI then it just puts the last command of the txt file

My code is:

```
    final JTextField Command[];//Create one dimensional array 
    Command = new JTextField[8];//Declare Command as a JTextField 
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)//Run the loop through each selection 
    { 
        Command[i] = new JTextField(i);//Read through each text field
    }
    //Add user input fields including their absolute position on the panel
    Command[1].setText("Please enter the commands...");//Starting text
    Command[1].setBounds(121, 13, 236, 25);//Set the position of the text field
    getContentPane().add(Command[1]);//Add this text field to the content
            Command[2].setBounds(121, 47, 236, 25);/fsdfsdf
    getContentPane().add(Command[2]);

    Command[3].setBounds(121, 83, 236, 25);/fasdfasd
    getContentPane().add(Command[3]);

    Command[4].setBounds(121, 119, 236, 25);/fsfasdasdf
    getContentPane().add(Command[4]);

    Command[5].setBounds(121, 155, 236, 25);
    getContentPane().add(Command[5]);

    Command[6].setBounds(121, 191, 236, 25);
    getContentPane().add(Command[6]);

    Command[7].setBounds(121, 227, 236, 25);
    getContentPane().add(Command[7]);  

            //IMPORT FILE   
    JMenuItem Import = new JMenuItem("Import");
    File.add(Import);
    Import.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//Call up ActionListener function
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {//Event handler
            try {
                //use buffering, reading one line at a time
                //FileReader always assumes default encoding is OK!
                BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("W:\\EclipsePortable\\Data\\workspace2\\" +
                                        "RobotController\\src\\RobotController\\Import commands.txt"));
                try {
                    String line = null; //not declared within while loop
                    while (( line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);//Print the lines
                        for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
                        Command[i].setText(line);
                    }
                }}
                finally {
                    input.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }});`
```

Comment: What behavior do you want? You want first input contain first line, second input - second line ant etc.?

Comment: Also please start variable name with lower case letter. It hard to read with upper case in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, in your file import code you are doing this...

```
for(int i = 1; i < 8; i++) {
    Command[i].setText(line);
```

Which is applying the current line of text to ALL the fields (the same line of text for all the fields), which means by the time you finish reading the file, you've only got the last line of the file.

Instead, I would keep a reference to the field index and increment in each line read

**Added Example**

```
                String line = null; //not declared within while loop
                int fieldIndex = 0;
                while (( line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);//Print 
                    Command[fieldIndex].setText(line);
                    fieldIndex++
                    if (fieldIndex > 7) {
                        break;
                    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked perfectly for me, although instead of fieldIndex++ I had to enter fieldIndex = fieldIndex + 1 as it wouldn't work properly for some reason ;o Thanks again :)

Comment: That's odd, fieldIndex++ is short hand for fieldIndex = fieldIndex + 1 or fieldIndex += 1

Comment: Exactly.. i think its somethin to do with software im using